# How to make confirmation when deleting files via terminal

Tags: command-line, konsole

```sh
cd Desktop/
rm bored.py
```

I want it to confirm before it removes.

(I use konsole btw)

Comment: While aliasing `rm` to `rm -i` seems like a solution, the better solution is to be careful when entering the command. `rm -i` just gives you a false feeling of safety: Imagine you rely on being asked before each deletion, and (for various reasons) no question is asked, and the deletion is done immediately.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by creating an alias for `rm` to include the flag for interactive deletes.

Here's how:

0. Open Konsole (if it's not already open)
1. Edit the `.bash_aliases` file:

   ```
   {editor of choice} .bash_aliases
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice} with your editor of choice.</sup>
2. Add an alias for `rm`:

   ```
   alias rm="rm -i"
   ```
3. Save the file and exit
4. Reload your profile:

   ```
   source ~/.profile
   ```

Now any time you try to delete a file, you'll see something like this:

```
$ rm bored.py 
rm: remove regular file 'bored.py'?
```

Pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> will delete the file. Pressing anything else will act as a "No", cancelling the operation.

**Note:** You can still use other flags despite the alias, so if you plan on removing lots of files, `rm -f *.py` will still work as expected *without* prompting for each individual file.

Answer (score 5):

Refer to the [man page of `rm`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/rm.1.html#:%7E:text=rm%20removes%20each%20specified%20file,proceed%20with%20the%20entire%20operation.):

> ```
>    -i     prompt before every removal
>
>    -I     prompt  once  before  removing more than three files, or when removing recursively.
>           Less intrusive than -i, while still giving protection against most mistakes
> ```

So, using `-i` flag with `rm` will give you a prompt similar to:

```
$ rm -i bored.py
rm: remove regular file 'bored.py'?
```

You can press <kbd>Y</kbd> will confirm the removal. Pressing <kbd>N</kbd> or any other key will deny the removal.

You can create an alias in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_alias` to make this flag permanent:

```
echo "alias rm='rm -i'" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

**NOTE**: This will only work on files when not used with the recursive (`-r`) or forceful (`-f`) flag.